# Firebase Robo test lab - ResourceID issue

Tags: firebase-test-lab

I am trying to test a login page from an APK I made and every test only enters the password i gave and not the Email. I have double checked the resourceID and tried using a script but the robo test still didn't enter the given Email

Comment: the error is this: Unused text input: no resource name matched the regex "edt_email"

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using the regex matcher for the resource ID. Based on the error message, the regex could be missing information necessary to match the resource. For example, resource IDs are usually at least prefixed by "id/" (sometimes the package name) and then the name of the resource: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Id